# can't assign to operator - python (overtime hours)

Tags: python

so I am trying to learn Python and am struggling with this question. Its asking to create a program where you enter the hours and the hour rate. for every hour worked over 40 the hour rate will be increased by a 1.5 rate. I've searched for the error (can't assign to operator) but all they say is that I can't assign a value to an expression.

```
horas = float(input("entra las horas trabajadas\n"))
porHora = float(input("entra cantidad por hora\n"))


overTime = 40.0                     #defining
otMult = 1.5

ganancias = (horas * porHora)

if horas > overTime :
    horas - overTime = overtimeHr
    (overtimeAm * porHora) * otMult = overtimeAm
    overtimeAm + ganancias = gananciasOt
    print(gananciasOt)

else :
    print(ganancias)
```

Comment: This looks like Python, not Ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment (both in Ruby and in Python) should be `variable = new_value_expression`, not `new_value_expression = variable`. All of your assignments are reversed. `horas - overTime` is not a variable, but an expression, thus the error. Instead of `horas - overTime = overTimeHr`, write `overTimeHr = horas - overTime` (and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code thanks to my boy Amadan ^^

```
horas = float(input("entra las horas trabajadas\n"))
porHora = float(input("entra cantidad por hora\n"))

                   #defining

ganancias = (horas * porHora)
preOt = (40 * porHora)

if horas > 40 :
    overtimeHr = horas - 40
    overtimeAm = (overtimeHr * porHora) * 1.5
    gananciasOt = overtimeAm + preOt
    print(gananciasOt)

else :
    print(ganancias)
```